# Linqpad truncate all numeric fields to 4 decimal places in dump output

Tags: c#, linq, decimal, truncate, linqpad

Does Linqpad have support for truncating numeric fields to a maximum number of decimal places similar to the "Results" configuration settings that apply to DateTime output:

[image]

Assuming Linqpad doesn't have built in support (no option in the Results settings tab), are there any other options?  I have an on object with over hundreds of `double` properties and I'm trying to avoid writing `Math.Round(obj.Property, 4, MidpointRound.ToZero)` 200 times.

Comment: No.  Numbers are stored in binary and does not convert to decimal places.  So only way of truncating to decimal places is first convert number to a string and then truncate the string.

Answer (score 2):

With Linqpad 7 you can customise the dump command by adding this to your query.

```
static object ToDump(object o)
{
    if (o is double d) return Math.Round(d, 4, MidpointRounding.ToZero);
    return o;
}
```

Example

```
void Main()
{
    Single s = 1.2345678f;
    Double d = (double) s;
    (new { s, d }).Dump();
}
```

By default this gives

[image]

but with the customised Dump it gives

[image]

See https://www.linqpad.net/CustomizingDump.aspx for more details.

You can also do this in your 'My Extensions' query and it can apply to all queries.

E.g. I have something like this in mine

```
public class Customisations
{        
    public static string intFormatString = null;
    public static string dateFormatString = null;
    public static string decimalFormatString = null;
    public static string doubleFormatString = null;    
}

static object ToDump(object input)
{   
    if (input is int      i  && Customisations.intFormatString     != null) return i.ToString(Customisations.intFormatString);
    if (input is decimal  de && Customisations.decimalFormatString != null) return de.ToString(Customisations.decimalFormatString);
    if (input is DateTime dt && Customisations.dateFormatString    != null) return dt.ToString(Customisations.dateFormatString);
    if (input is double   di && Customisations.doubleFormatString  != null) return di.ToString(Customisations.doubleFormatString);

    return input;
}
```

So I could add `Customisations.doubleFormatString = "#,##0.0000";` to my query to do something vaguely similar. (Not as precise as your example, but does what I want).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is want acoder is looking for, but the pointer on ToDump() is good stuff.  Does the `object input` passed into `ToDump()` get called for once for each object in a collection or does it get applied to an to objects properties?

Comment: @AdamCohen It is applied to everything including the properties of all the objects you dump. Also you don't need to call `ToDump()` directly, you just using the normal Dump command which calls ToDump if it exists. Hence I call .Dump() on a Entity/Table and it works on all the columns and also if I expand any links to other Entities/Tables.